# New automation variable by cli or ansible

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, azure-cli, azure-automation

After create a runbook and edit content, I want to create variable and set value for them. How can I do it by ansible or azure cli ?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

- Azure Automation stores each encrypted variable securely. When you create a variable, you can specify its encryption and storage by Azure Automation as a secure asset.
- You must set the value with the [Set-AzAutomationVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/set-azautomationvariable) cmdlet or the internal `Set-AutomationVariable` cmdlet. You use the `Set-AutomationVariable` in your runbooks that are intended to run in the Azure sandbox environment, or on a Windows Hybrid Runbook Worker.

You can create variables and set value for them using PowerShell script.

```
$rgName = "ResourceGroup01"
$accountName = "MyAutomationAccount"
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -Name "VM01" | Select Name, Location,Extensions
New-AzAutomationVariable -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount" -Name "MyComplexVariable" -Encrypted $false -Value $vm
$vmValue = Get-AzAutomationVariable -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount" -Name "MyComplexVariable"
$vmName = $vmValue.Value.Name
$vmTags = $vmValue.Value.Tags
```

Reference: [Manage variables in Azure Automation | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/variables?tabs=azure-powershell#create-and-get-a-variable-in-windows-powershell)